# Changing marker's size in stripplot according to data value

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, stripchart

I'm trying to create a categorical plot in which the size of each marker reflects some magnitude of the corresponding sample, as in the following example  using the preloaded tips data(upper plot https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRn0x.png):

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
 ax = sns.stripplot("day", "total_bill", data=tips, palette="Set2", size=tips["size"]*5, edgecolor="gray", alpha=.25)
```

But when I try the same with my own data, all the markers have the same size (lower plot  https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRn0x.png):

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("python_plot_test3.csv")
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
ax = sns.stripplot("log10p_value","term_name",  data=df, palette="Set2", size=df['precision'], edgecolor="gray", alpha=.50)
```

I suspected the datatypes were not the same, but it didn't seem so, 
although, when I print df['precision'] it returns name and dtype 
and when I print tips["size"] it also returns its length.
Could someone give me a hint? I found how to change it in scatter plots, but nothing on categorical plots.

---

my data data:

term_name,log10p_value,precision
muscle structure development,33.34122617,15
anatomical structure morphogenesis,32.91330177,5
muscle system process,31.61813233,11
regulation of multicellular organismal process,30.84862451,25
system development,29.16494157,36
muscle cell differentiation,28.79114555,11

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so looks like **relplot** is the right kind of function for this, at first I guessed it was specific for continuous data, but it also can handle categorized data. Although, I still don't understand why **stripplot** worked with the example data.